# Assumptions for RNNs

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, neural-networks, assumptions, recurrent-neural-network

Machine learning doesn't put emphasis on the assumptions for the data generating process, but on prediction. However, some assumptions must be made so that the trained model can be applied to new, unlabelled data.

**I'm interested in how these assumptions are formulated formally when working with sequential data, in particular when using RNNs.**

Say we have one or more sequences $x_{0,i},...,x_{T,i}$, for $i\in\{1,...N\}$. The number $N$ might also be $1$, in which case there is only one sequence. The elements of the sequences are realizations of random variables $X_{0,i},...,X_{T,i}$. The respective teaching sequences $y_{0,i},...,y_{T,i}$ are realizations of $Y_{0,i},...,Y_{T,i}$.

I can imagine at least two ways we would want to use a RNN:

1. Given the sequences above, for a new sequence $x_{0,N+1},...,x_{T,N+1}$ predict the corresponding sequence  $y_{0,N+1},...,y_{T,N+1}$.
2. Assume $N=1$, for $T'>T$, given $x_{0,1},...,x_{T',1}$ and $y_{0,1},...,y_{T,1}$ predict $y_{T+1,1},...,y_{T',1}$.

We consider the new values to be realizations of $X_{0,N+1},...,X_{T,N+1}$, $X_{T+1,1},...,X_{T',1}$, $Y_{0,N+1},...,Y_{T,N+1}$ and $Y_{T+1,1},...,Y_{T',1}$ respectively.

Which assumptions on the underlying processes are made when using a RNN to complete these tasks? Does it depend on which of the two above described cases applies? A an answer for only one of the two cases is also appreciated. You are also welcomed to formulate the assumptions in a different framework.